# Why is encrypting necessary for security after hashing in the UMAC (Universal Message Authentication Code) algorithm?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, theory, cryptographic-hash-function

On the Wikipedia for UMAC, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMAC, it states:

> The resulting digest or fingerprint is then encrypted to hide the
>   identity of the hash function used.

Further, in this paper, http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/umac-full.pdf, it states:

> A message is authenticated by hashing it with the shared hash function
>   and then encrypting the resulting hash (using the encryption key).

My question is, if the set of hash functions `H` is large enough, and the number of hash buckets `|B|` is large enough, why do we need to encrypt -- isn't the secret hash secure enough?

For example, take the worst case scenario where every client is sending the same, short content, like "x". If we hash to 32 bytes and our hash depends on a secret 32 byte hash key, and the hashes exhibit uniform properties, how could an attacker ever hope to learn the secret hash key of any individual client, even without encryption?

And, if the attacker doesn't learn the key, how could the attacker ever hope to maliciously alter the message contents?

Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, universal hash function families is something I never learned well.  But if I had time to research it now, I'd be looking at the old [Wegman and Carter paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000081900337) that the UMAC concept is based upon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about UMAC specifically but:

- Having a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) for a specific hash function defeats any encryption you have put on the message so instead of having a single attack surface, you now have two
- As computational powers increase with time you will be more and more likely to figure out the plaintext of the message so PFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) will never be possible if you leave the MAC unencrypted.
- On top of all this, if you can figure out a single plaintext message from a MAC value, you exponentially get closer to decrypting the rest of the message by getting some information about the PRNG, context of the other data, IV, etc.